# finding determinants using different properties

Tags: linear-algebra

The equation is as follows:

$\operatorname{det}(2A^{-1} + 7\operatorname{adj}(A))$

Here I know that $\operatorname{det}(A^{-1}) = (\operatorname{det}(A))^{-1}$ and $\operatorname{det}(kA) = k^n \operatorname{det}(A)$

using these, we know that $\operatorname{det}((2A)^{-1} )= \frac{1}{4} \operatorname{det}(A)^{-1} =\frac{1}{8}$

I do not know a formula that relates to adjoints in this case besides maybe:

$$A \operatorname{adj}(A) = \operatorname{det}(A)I$$

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be clear improve the formatting

Comment: does that mean that formula does not apply here?

Comment: I edited your question to $\LaTeX$ify it, so it reads better.  A question of my own:  how do we know that $2A^{-1} = 1/4 \det(A) = 1/8$?  Is that a given?  Cheers!

Comment: Or perhaps you meant to write $(\det(2A))^{-1} = 1/(4\det(A))$ etc.  But where does $1/(4\det(A)) = 1/8$ come from?  Again, is that a given?  And again, Cheers!

Comment: Or are we to assume $\det(A) = 2$?

Comment: well in a previous similar question that i had which was det((2A)^-1B^2) i found out that (2A)^-1 gives me 1/k^n det(A) which means --> 1/2^2 det(A) . The determinants of A & B were given and they're respectively det(A) = 2 & det(B) = 3 but here det(B) is not needed

Comment: sorry btw for the missing piece of information for the det(A) = 2 which was yes indeed given

Comment: Good!  I recommend you edit your question, using $\LaTeX$ if possible (you can probably learn how to do it by checking out my edits), and add the information that $\det(A) = 2$; add some information, if you can, about why this problem interests you; doing these things  will help protect your question against "closure" and eventual deletion!  Best of Luck with it!

Comment: @marwalix  as I see it, the equation $A\operatorname{adj}(A) = \det(A) I$ implies $\operatorname{adj}(A) = \det(A) A^{-1}$; what do you think?

Comment: My mistake with all the operatorname one eventually gets mixed up

Comment: @marwalix:  I know, that "\operatorname" is a pain in the ass!

Comment: I have edited it all comment and answer. I hope it is ok by now

Comment: @marwalix:  it's OK, except that $\det(A) = 2 \Rightarrow 2 + 7\det(A) = 16$!

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{det}(2A^{-1} + 7\operatorname{adj}(A))
&=\operatorname{det}\left((2+7\operatorname{det}(A))A^{-1}\right)\\
&=\operatorname{det}(k\cdot A^{-1})\\
&=k^n\operatorname{det}(A^{-1})\\
&=\left(2+7\operatorname{det}(A)\right)^{n}\left(\operatorname{det}A\right)^{-1}
\end{align}$$

With $n=2$ and $\operatorname{det}(A)=2$ we have

$$\operatorname{det}(2A^{-1} + 7\operatorname{adj}(A))=\frac{16^2}{2}=128$$

Comment: i don't quite understand this whole procedure. what are the relevant sample formula's in practice here?

Comment: where is that A^-1 at the end coming from ?

Comment: I just edited for more clarity and I am using two properties of the determinant $\operatorname{det}(k\cdot A)=k^n\operatorname{det}(A)$ and $\operatorname{det}(A)\cdot A^{-1}=\operatorname{adj}(A)$

Comment: YOU GOT IT!  ***YAAAAAYYYY!!!*** Cheers!

Comment: Tired with the operatorname! I had enough for today

Answer (score 1):

Look at this:

since

$A\operatorname{adj}(A) = \det(A)I, \tag{1}$

we have

$\operatorname{adj}(A) = \det(A) A^{-1} \tag{2}$

provided $A^{-1}$ exists.  Well, since we are given that (see comments above)

$\det(A) = 2, \tag{3}$

we know $A^{-1}$ *does* indeed exist, so using (2) we have

$2A^{-1} + 7\operatorname{adj}(A) = 2A^{-1} + 7\det(A)A^{-1} = (2 + 7\det(A))A^{-1}$
$= (2 + 7(2))A^{-1} = 16A^{-1}, \tag{4}$

whence

$\det(2A^{-1} + 7\operatorname{adj}(A)) = \det(16A^{-1}) = (16)^n (\det(A))^{-1},\tag{5}$

where $n = \operatorname{size}(A)$.  Now since

$\operatorname{det}((2A)^{-1} )= \frac{1}{4} \operatorname{det}(A)^{-1} =\frac{1}{8}, \tag{6}$

with

$\det(2A) = 2^n \det(A) \tag{7}$

and

$\det((2A)^{-1}) = (\det(2A))^{-1}, \tag{8}$

we see that

$2^{-n} = \dfrac{1}{4}, \tag{9}$

which shows that $n = 2$; thus (5) yields

$\det(2A^{-1} + 7\operatorname{adj}(A)) = \det(16A^{-1})$
$= (16)^2(\det(A))^{-1} = 256 (\det(A))^{-1} = \dfrac{256}{2} = 128.\tag{10}$